# Как сделать чтобы AutoIncrement в dataGridView увеличивался только при добавлении строки

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

**Код**

```
   // *** создаю DataTable
dt_028 = new DataTable();

// *** Добавляю поля в DataTable
// поле Автоинкремент
workColumn = dt_028.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
workColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
workColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
workColumn.AutoIncrementStep = 1;

// поля DataTable
dt_028.Columns.Add("pole_name_1", typeof(String));
dt_028.Columns.Add("pole_name_2", typeof(String));
dt_028.Columns.Add("pole_name_3", typeof(String));

// *** Отображаю DataTable в dataGridView
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt_028;
```

Когда перемещаю курсор в dataGridView с предпоследней строки на последнюю, увеличивается значение AutoIncrement в поле "ID".
Т.е. переместил курсор на последнюю строку, но строку не добавил, а AutoIncrement увеличился.

**ВОПРОС**
Как сделать чтобы автоинкремент увеличивался только при добавлении строки dataGridView, а не просто при нахождении курсора на последней строке?

**СКРИН**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: идеальное оформление вопроса

Comment: А что есть добавление строки перенести на отдельную кнопку и уже по её нажатию будет увеличиваться инкремент? Либо запускать инкремент по свойству CellBeginEdit, тогда только после ввода данных он будет наращиваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, перемещение на последнюю строку в `DataGridView` а потом обратно, приводит к тому, что в `DataTable`, который указан в качестве источника данных, вставляется новая строка. Вставка новой строки приводит к инкременту поля `ID`, но т.к. строка на самом деле вставлена не была, происходит отклонение последних изменений - `DataTable.RejectChanges()`, *т.е. тех изменений, которые произошли с момента последнего вызова* `DataTable.AcceptChanges()`, при этом значение инкремента **не сбрасывается**, в связи с чем при новом перемещении на последную строку в `DataGridView` значение `ID` не то, которое вы ожидали увидеть.

Что можно сделать?

**Решение № 1**

Инкрементировать вручную, т.е. отключить `workColumn.AutoIncrement` на колонке `ID` и выставлять значение самостоятельно.

```
private void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _dt = new DataTable();

    // Подписываемся на событие вставки новой строки.
    _dt.TableNewRow += DataTableNewRow;

    _dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    _dt.Columns.Add("pole_name_1", typeof(string));
    _dt.Columns.Add("pole_name_2", typeof(string));
    _dt.Columns.Add("pole_name_3", typeof(string));

    _dataGridView.DataSource = _dt;
}

private void DataTableNewRow(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs dataTableNewRowEventArgs)
{
    // Инкрементируем ID.
    dataTableNewRowEventArgs.Row["ID"] = _dt.Rows.Count + 1;
}
```

**Решение № 2**

Возложить задачу по генерации `ID` на вашу БД, что на мой взгляд более правильно.

**Решение № 3**

Вместо типа `int` использовать тип `Guid`, при условии необходимости генерации `ID` на клиенте.

Answer (score 2):

Убрать автоинкремент у данного столбца. Остаётся лишь:

```
workColumn = dt_028.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
```

Подписать `DataTable` на событие добавления новой строки:

```
dt_028.TableNewRow += Dt_028_TableNewRow;
```

В обработчике события вставляем нужное значение:

```
private void Dt_028_TableNewRow(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row["ID"] = dt_028.Rows.Count;
}
```

---

Ещё лучше вообще убрать эту колонку (вариант - сделать её скрытой). А номера строкам давать при сохранении данных в БД/файл. Собственно, а нужны ли вообще эти номера? В БД айдишник должен быть свой. А в файле он не нужен.